# -self parentViewController- dismissModalViewController not working on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

So, any clue on this? I had to use [self dismiss modalviewcontroller to dismiss modalviews. Funny fact: when dismissing a tabbarcontroller I could still use the reference to parentviewcontroller, when dismissing a regular viewcontroller, not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On iOS 5 you will need to use the `presentingViewController` selector instead of the `parentViewController` selector.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I just wish the compiler would give any hint on that, how the hell are people suposed to know it? Read the whole damn documentation?

Comment: The problem is that existing 4.x code no longer works in iOS5 devices using parentViewController. Also, if I use presentingViewController, any 4.x code crashes because it doesn't recognize the selector.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  I'm starting to get a very bad feeling about iOS5.

Comment: Thanks Jason and Vinnie! This iOS 5 is starting to create pain for me :(

Comment: @Vinnie - It's not the greatest solution but you can always implement a method to conditionally determine what selector should be used to get the presenting/parent VC.  
  
    -(UIViewController*) getPresentingViewController:(UIImagePickerController*) picker {
    return ([picker respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)] ? [picker presentingViewController] : [picker parentViewController]);    
}

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the work-arounds. I ended up using a customParentViewController property that I created myself. My bone to pick is with my previous apps in the app store. They're broken. Some I haven't updated in a long time and didn't really want to dive into the code to fix Apples problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
-(UIViewController *)getParentViewController{   
    float currentVersion = 5.0;
    float sysVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (sysVersion >= currentVersion) {
        // iOS 5.0 or later version of iOS specific functionality hanled here 
           return self.presentingViewController;
    }
    else {
        //Previous than iOS 5.0 specific functionality
           return self.parentViewController;

    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `[self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)];`. Also, don't prefix the method with `get`.

Comment: +1 for @IvanVučica. Making decisions based on the system version is poor form. Let the object tell you instead.

Answer (score 1):

The app i have in the store was built using ios SDK 4.3 and uses `self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES`.   It continues to work with IOS 5 devices.  I thought it would since it was built on sdk 4.3.   Now when i'm updating it with the new xcode and ios 5.0 sdk, it will not work as is and i have to change all the view closing stuff to use the conditional selector  workaround mentioned above.(yuck!)

Just thought i'd mention that dismissing from the parent should work on ios 5 (at least in my case with the ios 4.3 sdk).   I can't speak for previous sdks or other selectors with parentViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a category that add `presentingViewController` on iOS 4.

It disables itself on iOS 5.

You can use it seamlessly. Please see [backward-modal](http://github.com/tanin47/backward-modal.git).

Answer (score 0):

For your particular use case of dismissing the modal view controller, you may want to keep in mind the **second paragraph** of the Discussion section in Apple's documentation for `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

> The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal
>   view controller it presented using the
>   presentModalViewController:animated: method. If you call this method
>   on the modal view controller itself, however, the modal view
>   controller automatically forwards the message to its parent view
>   controller.
>
> If you call this method on the modal view controller itself, however,
>   the modal view controller automatically forwards the message to its
>   parent view controller.

Jason's solution is also great and helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice blog post explaining this issue:

http://omegadelta.net/2011/11/04/oh-my-god-they-killed-parentviewcontroller/

Following this post I created a category method for UIViewController:

```
- (UIViewController*) myParentViewController {
    UIViewController* ret = [self parentViewController];
    if(ret == nil) {
        if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
            ret = [self presentingViewController];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```